# abcde ripping to wav

Tags: audio, ripping, wav

I am trying to find out configuration for abcde to extract a cd to wav. 
I am using mp3 config file from http://www.andrews-corner.org/abcde.html

but I dont know what the wav encoder or abcde configs should be .

I know that there are other ways to encode a cd-->wav but I want to do it with abcde.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

abcde rips the tracks to wav first (nearly a 1-to-1 rip) then encodes them.  You can set "KEEPWAVS=y" on any of those configs to keep these temporary files.  To keep it from converting the wav files, remove the "encode" string from the "ACTIONS" option.  Keep in mind that the wav files produced via this method will be unprocessed, none of the other actions that abcde takes on the data will have occured on these files, such as volume limiting and renaming.

You could also simply set "OUTPUTTYPE=wav"